# AWK Escape double quotes in Winawk / Gnuwin

Tags: awk, escaping, double-quotes

I cant figure out, how to search for a word in AWK, Gnuwin. I have the following in AWK:

..."{ if ($2==""""Word"""") print }"...

The Word is written with double quotes in my file, so I have to search for it with double quotes.

I've tried:
..."{ if ($2=="""\"Word\"""") print }"...
and many other ways, which do not work.

Has anyone a idea of how this will work?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Windows shell, you have to escape double quotes inside a script with a backslash if you are entering the script on the command line. And, those double quotes, if they are part of some string, must be escaped by a backslash due to AWK's rules, and since that backslash is inside a string, it too has to be escaped by backslash:

```
gawk "$2 == \"\\\"Word\\\"\" {print $2}"
```

This will print any line whose second token is: *"Word"*.

Breaking it down with some whitespace:

```
O   B   LQ  WORD  B   LQ  C
\"  \\  \"  Word  \\  \"  \"

O == Opening quote of the string to search for.
B == A backslash that will escape the following character
LQ == A literal double quote (because of the preceding backslash)
WORD == the literal text 'Word'
C == Closing quote of the string to search for.
```

If the test wasn't on the command line, it would look a bit better:

```
$2 == "\"Word\""
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was searching for this the whole day!

Comment: or just put it in a file and don't backslash anything !